# Can we find the asymptotic behavior of this $f(x) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^2}{1+\frac{e^{u^2}}{x}}du$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, special-functions

I encountered this function in Statistical Mechanics.  $$f(x) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^2}{1+\frac{e^{u^2}}{x}}du$$ 
For $x=0$, we define its value to be zero.
I wanted to see it's asymptotic behavior in the limit x tending to $\infty$. Can we express the asymptotic behavior of this function, in the limit x tending to $\infty$, in terms of other known mathematical functions (if possible; in elementary functions)? For some physical reasons (which are irrelevant here), $x$ belongs to $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a first step, we perform the substitution $v=e^{u^2}$. we obtain
$$ f(x) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^2}{1+\frac{e^{u^2}}{x}}du = \int_1^\infty \frac{(\ln v)^{1/2}}{2 v(1+v/x)} dv \;.$$

Next, we take a look at the function 
$$ f_0(x) = \int_1^x \frac{(\ln v)^{1/2}}{2 v } dv =\frac13 (\ln x)^{3/2}$$
The intuition for this is that the integral for $f(x)$ is dominated for $v \lesssim x$. In this region the integral is approximately given by the expression above.

Indeed, we have
$$f(x) - f_0(x) = -\int_1^x \frac{(\ln v)^{1/2}}{2(x+v)} dv+ \int_x^\infty \frac{(\ln v)^{1/2}}{2 v(1+v/x)} dv;$$
with the estimates
$$\int_1^x \frac{(\ln v)^{1/2}}{2(x+v)} dv  < \int_1^x \frac{(\ln x)^{1/2}}{2x} dv <\frac{(\ln x)^{1/2}}{2} $$
and
$$\int_x^\infty \frac{(\ln v)^{1/2}}{2 v(1+v/x)} dv < \frac{x}{2}\int_x^\infty \frac{(\ln v)^{1/2}}{ v^2} dv = \frac12 (\ln x)^{1/2} + \frac{x}{4} \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{v^2(\ln v)^{1/2}} dv \\< \frac12 (\ln x)^{1/2} +\frac{x}{4 (\ln x)^{1/2}} \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{v^2} dv < \frac12 (\ln x)^{1/2} + \frac{1}{4 (\ln x)^{1/2}}\;. $$

With this, we have established that
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3} (\ln x)^{3/2} + O(\ln^{1/2} x).$$

Answer (score 5):

**1. (Not so illuminating) analytic expression.** Assume for a moment that $0 < x < 1$. Then

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xu^2e^{-u^2}}{1 + xe^{-u^2}} \, du
 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} x^n \int_{0}^{\infty} u^2 e^{-nu^2} \, du \\
&= -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n^{3/2}}
 = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(-x).
\end{align*}

The last function is analytic outside $(-\infty, -1]$, and hence this identity extends to all of $x \geq 0$ by the principle of analytic continuation. But this is not so useful when investigating the asymptotic bahavior of $f(x)$.

**2. Asymptotic expansion.** Write $\alpha = \log x$ and make the substitution $u = \sqrt{\alpha(v+1)}$. Then

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \frac{\alpha^{3/2}}{2} \int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+v}}{1 + e^{\alpha v}} \, dv \\
&= \frac{\alpha^{3/2}}{2} \left( \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-v} \, dv - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-v}}{1 + e^{\alpha v}} \, dv + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+v}}{1 + e^{\alpha v}} \, dv \right).
\end{align*}

This easily yields the following asymptotics

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{3}(\log x)^{3/2} + \mathcal{O}\left( (\log x)^{1/2} \right). $$

For a better resolution, recall that the polylogarithm is defined as $\operatorname{Li}_s(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^s}$ for $|z| < 1$. Then

$$ \frac{1}{1 + e^{\alpha v}} = -\operatorname{Li}_0(-e^{-\alpha v}), \qquad \frac{d}{dv} \operatorname{Li}_{s+1}(-e^{-\alpha v}) = - \alpha \operatorname{Li}_s(-e^{-\alpha v}) $$

and hence

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+v}}{1 + e^{\alpha v}} \, dv
&= -\int_{0}^{\infty} (1+v)^{1/2} \operatorname{Li}_0(-e^{-\alpha v}) \, dv \\
&= -\frac{\operatorname{Li}_1(-1)}{\alpha} - \frac{1}{2\alpha} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_1(-e^{-\alpha v})}{(1+v)^{1/2}} \, dv \\
&= -\frac{\operatorname{Li}_1(-1)}{\alpha} - \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)}{2\alpha^2} + \frac{1}{4\alpha^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-\alpha v})}{(1+v)^{3/2}} \, dv
\end{align*}

and, in principle, the same argument can be applied to extract an asymptotic expansion up to any fixed order. Similarly,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-v}}{1 + e^{\alpha v}} \, dv
&= -\int_{0}^{1} (1-v)^{1/2} \operatorname{Li}_0(-e^{-\alpha v}) \, dv \\
&= -\frac{\operatorname{Li}_1(-1)}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{2\alpha} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_1(-e^{-\alpha v})}{(1-v)^{1/2}} \, dv \\
&= -\frac{\operatorname{Li}_1(-1)}{\alpha} + \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) - \operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-\alpha})}{2\alpha^2} \\
&\qquad + \frac{1}{4\alpha^2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-\alpha v}) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-\alpha})}{(1-v)^{3/2}} \, dv
\end{align*}

and so on. Using the results above, we obtain a better asymptotics

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{3} (\log x)^{3/2} + \frac{\pi^2}{24} \frac{1}{(\log x)^{1/2}} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{(\log x)^{3/2}} \right). $$

Comment: Indeed, the last term must be $\displaystyle\mathcal{O}\left(1 \over \left(\log x\right)^{\color{red}{5}/2}\right)$.

Comment: @FelixMarin, Thank you for your answer. Indeed I was quite sure that there is a well-known asymptotic expansion of polylogarithms of fractional orders, but was lazy enough not to look for it and just to stick to chunky computations.

Comment: It's always useful anyway.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{x} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{u^{2} \over 1 + \expo{u^{2}}/x}\,\dd u 
\,\,\,\stackrel{u^{2}\ \mapsto\ u}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{u^{1/2} \over \expo{u}/x + 1}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{3 \over 2}\mrm{Li}_{3/2}\pars{-x}
=
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\root{\pi}\,\mrm{Li}_{3/2}\pars{-x}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> See the [Polylogarithm Integral Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Integral_representations).

By using the [Polylogarithm Asymptotic Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Asymptotic_expansions), \eqref{1}
becomes ( $\ds{B_{n}}$ is a [Bernoulli Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) )

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{x} & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\root{\pi}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{1 - 2^{1 - 2k}}\pars{2\pi}^{2k}\,
{B_{2k} \over \pars{2k}!}\,{\ln^{3/2 - 2k}\pars{x} \over \Gamma\pars{5/2 - 2k}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{1 \over 3}\,\ln^{3/2}\pars{x} + {\pi^{2} \over 24}\,\ln^{-1/2}\pars{x} +
{7\pi^{4} \over 1920}\,\ln^{-5/2}\pars{x} +
\mrm{O}\pars{\ln^{-9/2}\pars{x}}}
\\ & \mbox{as}\ x\ \to\ \infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We have a linear upper bound: $$f=\int_0^\infty\frac{xu^2e^{-u^2}}{1+xe^{-u^2}}du\le x\int_0^\infty u^2e^{-u^2} du.$$But we also have a $O(1)$ lower bound: $$f\ge\frac{x}{1+xe^{-1}}\int_0^1u^2e^{-u^2}du=\frac{\int_0^1u^2e^{-u^2}du}{1/x+e^{-1}}.$$

Comment: The [integral in the first](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+u%5E2e%5E(-u%5E2)+from+0+to+infinity) is $\frac {\sqrt \pi}4 \approx 0.443$  The [integral in the second](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+u%5E2e%5E(-u%5E2)+from+0+to+1) is about $0.1895$